# frame in environment and note fail in beamer

Tags: beamer

Using `beamer`, if I define a `\newenvironment` that starts and ends a `frame`, a subsequent `note` fails.

Why, and how to fix this?

In the below minimal example (changed in response to comments), the frame always compiles, but the note fails when using the `\myframe` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\newenvironment{myframe}%
{\begin{frame}[environment=myframe]\frametitle{SomeTitle} SomeContent}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame} Test \end{frame} % works
\begin{myframe} Test \end{myframe} % fails when compiling the note

\note[itemize]
{
    \item Note test
}

\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\itemize ...ix item}##1}}}}} \fi \beamer@cramped 
                                                  \raggedright 
\beamer@first...
```

The output from `pdflatex` is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2020/07/22 v3.59 A class for typesetting presentations
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/xxcolor.sty)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaserequires.sty

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecompatibility.st
y) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasefont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sansmathaccent/sansmathaccent.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetranslator.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetwoscreens.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoverlay.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetitle.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasesection.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframe.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseverbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframesize.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframecomponents.
sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenotes.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetoc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetemplates.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseboxes.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.s
ty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenavigation.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetheorems.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasethemes.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerthemedefault.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerfontthemedefault.sty
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamercolorthemedefault.st
y)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerinnerthemedefault.st
y)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerouterthemedefault.st
y)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty)) (./test.out) (./test.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dicti
onary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-bibliograph
y-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-environment
-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-months-dict
ionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-numbers-dic
tionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-theorem-dic
tionary-English.dict) (./test.nav) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/m
ap/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! Undefined control sequence.
\\itemize ...ix item}##1}}}}} \fi \beamer@cramped 
                                                  \raggedright \beamer@first...
l.15 }
      
? 
! Emergency stop.
\\itemize ...ix item}##1}}}}} \fi \beamer@cramped 
                                                  \raggedright \beamer@first...
l.15 }
      
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: I can't confirm your findings.  Compilation works, i.e. no warnings, no errors (tested by Beamer version 3.59). However, I can't figured out, what is purpose of your new  environment.  That all frames will have the same title? Please elaborate

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. I updated the question. The purpose is to have several variants of `frame` which differ mostly optically, e.g., summaries, learning objectives.

Comment: Wel, let me repeat, I cant confirm your problems. Also is not clear purpose of option in your `myframe` definition. As it is now You can simple delete it and the result will be the same as before.  Please elaborate your question.

Comment: I updated my texlive installation, still the same. @zarko If you delete the `myframe` environment, the frametitle will change, for example. The actual environments have more but simple changes (some colors change, default itemize list for content, ...) There might be a more clever way to do that with `beamer`.

Comment: I also can not reproduce your problem. Add `\listfiles` at the top of your `tex` file (before `\documentclass{beamer}`) and add the console output to your question.

Comment: Also, possibly unrelated, but you've defined your environment to take an argument, but not explicitly provided one when you call it. To avoid surprises you should use `\begin{myframe}{Some text} Test \end{myframe}` At present for your example code the argument (`#1`) is `T` and the body of environment is `est`.

Comment: @DavidPurton The parameter was a bug, thanks. Still the same though. I added the output with `\listfiles` at top of document.

Comment: Now you have changed your example code, I can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize `\beamer@cramped` in the preamble using

```
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@cramped{}
\makeatother
```

For your example, use it as

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\newenvironment{myframe}%
{\begin{frame}[environment=myframe]\frametitle{SomeTitle} SomeContent}
{\end{frame}}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@cramped{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame} Test \end{frame} % works
\begin{myframe} Test \end{myframe} % fails when compiling the note

\note[itemize]
{
    \item Note test
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the document compiles now. Could you elaborate briefly on the purpose of `\beamer@cramped`? What functionality is lost when removing the original definition? The documentation does not seem to mention "cramped".

Comment: @mrupp My guess is that nothing is lost. Apparently, in your particular situation, the part where this macro is initialized by `\def\beamer@cramped{}` is skipped, so later you get the error that you see. I modified my solution to match the initialization used in the style file.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess why this happens it would have to be beamer's way of looking for `\end{frame}` and frame fragility and what not. Beamer in general does not much like new frames.

I've noticed though that if there's a regular frame before your environment it still works. That frame can even be a title frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\newenvironment{myframe}
{\begin{frame}[environment=myframe]\frametitle{SomeTitle} SomeContent}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

 \begin{myframe}
     Test 
 \end{myframe} 

\note[itemize]
{
    \item Note test
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: my guess is that you had -1 votes because you didn’t answer their question, but your “comment” totally helped me out. I have to make sure not to \note until a \begin{frame} has passed (possibly also \end{frame})